# Can svn up display commit messages since the last up?

Tags: svn

When I use `svn up`, it would be handy to have a list of commit messages since I last updated. Is this possible?

Comment: How do you get it to display log messages since your last up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
svn log -r <your-revision>:HEAD
```

You can get your revision number by using svn info. You can check http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.0/re15.html for more options